# ASP.NET Core - difference between Output caching and Response caching

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, caching, http-caching

ASP.NET Core 7 preview 6 just introduced [Output caching](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-dotnet-7-preview-6/#output-caching-middleware) which caches the endpoint output. However ASP.NET already has [Response caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/middleware?view=aspnetcore-6.0) which seems to already provide the same feature.
What is the difference between the two and when should one be used and when should the other be used?

Comment: there is very interesting [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RYw2pyG74YM) by Microsoft which explains the difference in great detail.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was looking for answers and trying to understand the differences between both, and really took a huge amount of time to understand the differences between the two, and when (or not) to use each other.

As of November 2022 .Net 7 has been released, but the documentation is not very clear about the differences between them. The documentation and all videos only talk about the `OutputCache` as a replacement for the `ResponseCache`.
Also searching for `OutputCache`, it comes up with a lot of results from the old AspNet (Full framework) MVC 5.

So let´s clarify the differences and how we could use each other.

**ResponseCache**

First, the ResponseCache can be divided in 2 parts, that work independently and are different concepts of how and where the information would be cached. Let´s catch them up:

1. [ResponseCacheAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-7.0): Basically it manipulates cache header like `Vary`, `Cache-Control` and others. It works telling the browsers or proxies to store (or not) the response content. This technique can reduce the number of requests done to the server, if used correctly.

> The ResponseCache attribute sets response caching headers. Clients and
> intermediate proxies should honor the headers for caching responses.
> under the HTTP 1.1 Caching specification

2. [Response Caching Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/middleware?view=aspnetcore-7.0): Basically, it is used to make server-side caching based on headers defined by `ResponseCacheAttribute`. Depending on the Request Headers sent to the server, the response would never be cached on server side.

> Enables caching server responses based on HTTP cache headers.
> Implements the standard HTTP caching semantics. Caches based on HTTP
> cache headers like proxies do.

> Is typically not beneficial for UI apps such as Razor Pages because
> browsers generally set request headers that prevent caching. Output
> caching, which is available in ASP.NET Core 7.0 and later, benefits UI
> apps. With output caching, configuration decides what should be cached
> independently of HTTP headers.

And at this point that `OutputCache` comes as a replacement for `Response Caching Middleware`.

**OutputCache** *(available in ASP.NET Core 7.0 and later)*

The [OutputCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/output?view=aspnetcore-7.0) configuration decides what should be cached (server side) independently of HTTP headers. Also, it comes with a lot of [new features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/overview?view=aspnetcore-7.0#output-caching) like cache entry invalidation, storage medium extensibility and [others](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/overview?view=aspnetcore-7.0#output-caching).

**Conclusion**

To take the benefits from both worlds you can use:

- [ResponseCacheAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-7.0): To manipulate response headers and enable the clients/proxies to store content on `client side`;
- [OutputCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/output?view=aspnetcore-7.0): To store responses on `server side` and increase throuthput when responses are cached.

Both works independently. You can choose the one that fits best you application.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't watch the video CodingMytra provided. But I think `Output caching` has some enhancements over `Response caching`. For example, you can specify a few seconds of caching.

I found [a useful video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EMS4DjpRvJQ&t=1953s), and it has some demos you learn more about the `Output caching` in .Net7. I think you can find the difference in this video.

We can find out why there is a need for Output caching in this github issue.

Link :  [Add support for Output Caching #27387](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/27387)

Answer (score 0):

The most significant difference is that ResponseCache is to cache on the client side, while OutputCache is on the server side. Assuming you're firing the same request from two different browsers, you won't benefit from ResponseCache but OutputCache. Of course, using OutputCache will consume your server-side resources but with ResponseCache, you don't have to worry about it.